# Bus Seat Reservation in Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing Bus Reservation System but i am stack on how to implement this situation.

I will use this funny example of countries so you can get an idea.

A Bus main Route is from USA To China but it have some stop points like England, India and Russia.

Main Route 
USA To CHINA

Sub-Route
USA To ENGLAND 
ENGLAND To INDIA
INDIA To RUSSIA 
RUSSIA To CHINA

The logic i need a help to implement is

1. if a Passenger board from USA and off board in England sat on A1 seat what logic should i use when another passenger want to book the same seat A1 from England to India or Russia???
2. I need advice which logic should i use when a seat B1 lets say was booked from England to China what logic should i use when passengers from India & Russia to China to show them that seat B1 is booked.

I tried to brainstorm this situation whole day without any success. Need help guys.

Comment: [A bus trip from New Jersey to Shanghai is going to be an *interesting* journey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_School_Bus_(TV_series)). Reservation systems are fundamentally a resource allocation problem, and these are often quite tricky to get right. This is not a simple question to answer.

Comment: Any idea how to implement this? @tadman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of thinking of reservations being for a whole trip, instead think of reservations being for each step of the trip.

Lets say your bus route is: USA to Russia to China to England to India.  If i book a seat from USA to India then in your system treat it like I booked 4 trips with the same seat.

Someone might book B1 England to India, then if I want B1 for USA to india, I should be able to see that it is only available for USA to England.  I would need to book a different seat for England to India or go on a different day if they are all full.

Here is a very, very, very basic DB concept:

- Trips: have many steps
- id, name, date
- steps_trips: lookup table
- id, step_id, trip_id
- Steps: have many trips
- id, startpoint, endpoint, start_time, end_time
- busses_steps: lookup table
- id, buss_id, step_id
- Busses: have many seats, have many steps
- id, name, vin
- Seats: belongs to busses
- id, name, buss_id

So the idea here is that you might have several busses running several different routes.  A traveler can pick a trip then your system can choose the busses and seats based on availability and time.

This is a very involved problem so I suggest starting small the building up.  You will need a way to handle reserved seating as well as cancelations, and it would be a good idea to present the available seats visually somehow in your system as well.

Comment: Sound promising, if possible can you try to draft simple tables so i can get the real image? @The Dog

Comment: I am starting to get the logic, let me try to modify my tables then see where i will stack. Thanks for the  help.